# Maven Repository

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I have downloaded all artifacts in maven repository. Now I copied the repository folder content to other computer running maven. I have to access this new repository for maven commands but it is trying to connect to net for downloading artifacts required. What should I do?? 
Is there any way of using such repository created manually??

Answer (score 1):

Are you using snapshot versions of your dependencies? If so, Maven might still try to connect to a remote repository to check if there is a new version available. However, you can avoid this by using -o (=offline), like this:

```
mvn -o <your_command>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the correct path to the maven repository in your settings.xml file?

Comment: Hi <localRepository>~/.m2/repository</localRepository>
 
  <interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
  
   <offline>true</offline> ... In setting.xml file i have made the foll changes. Do I have to make some more changes in that??

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you might have a different version of Maven on your new machine and thus, it will try to install all the new compatible plugins while you try to build it. So there is no way to get around it except for using exactly the same maven version and same settings